# Befriend default constructor: clang produces parse error while gcc did not

Tags: c++, clang, friend-function

I encountered a confusing issue. For following snippet:

```
class A { };
class E
{
    friend A::A() throw();
};
```

I used Clang 6 to compile this code example and got "error: non-constexpr declaration of 'A' follows constexpr declaration". I also tried clang 4.0, clang 5.0 and gcc 5.4 and there were no this kind of error. Is this a bug in Clang6?

Comment: Seems like [Clang says](https://godbolt.org/g/n5H7c8) that `constexpr` is part of the signature of `A::A()`, and it doesn't allow mismatched signatures. If you add `constexpr` to the friend declaration, [it works](https://godbolt.org/g/ayaamc)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't error in clang 4.0?  On godbolt it errors all the way back to 3.4.1: https://godbolt.org/g/m6BiiW

Comment: I used Clang 6.0, and changed the line to `friend constexpr A::A() noexcept;`, and it worked.  I compiled with `clang++ -c -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded --std=c++17 Sunshine.cpp`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the compiler-generated default constructor counts as a declaration, but clang might be complaining because [`[dcl.constexpr]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#:specifier,constexpr) states, "If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the constexpr specifier." The compiler generated default constructor is `constexpr`, but your friend declaration doesn't mark it as `constexpr`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I used clang-4.0 <test file> without any compilation options and there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

From [class.ctor#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#7)

> the implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr

Since there is no user-declared constructor for `class A`, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted

However,

```
friend A::A() throw();
```

You explicitly declare `A::A()` which doesn't match the implicitly-declared constructor (which is a [`constexpr constructor`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#4)).

Specifically:

> either its function-body shall be = default, or the compound-statement
>   of its function-body shall satisfy the requirements for a
>   function-body of a constexpr function;